# Fastest way to install types for node packages?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

Every time I want to use typed packages in my Nodejs projects, I have to do two things:

- First, install the original package. Eg: `npm install express -S`
- Second, install the its type definition package. `npm install @types/express -D`

My problem is I feel lazy and a little bit tired when i have to do two steps to be able to use one more package. Is there any ways to do this faster/smarter?

Comment: Any kind of repetitive work can be automated. Make yourself a script.

Comment: Wow I even don't know that if there is already a way to achieve this so I don't have to spend time to reinvent the wheel. How it's even worth a downvote?

Comment: can't comment on down-vote, but declaring your dependencies in the `package.json` not help ?

Comment: One way is to ask vscode to support type acquisition for TypeScript as they have in JavaScript. And then make it configurable to install the typings locally per project instead of in vscode cache location. :)

Answer (score 4):

How about Bash expansion?

If you can afford to use a Bash-compatible shell (e.g. you are on Linux/macOS/cygwin), you can use the brace expansion feature of your shell:

```
npm i -S {,@types/}express
```

That's equivalent to:

```
npm i -S express @types/express
```

The issue with this, though, is that both the package and typings for it will be saved as `dependencies`, not `devDependencies` in `package.json`. We also might want to install several packages (and types for them) at the same time. So let's improve our command to account for that:

```
echo express lodash | xargs -n 1 -I % sh -c 'npm i -S %; npm i -D @types/%'
```

This will install both `express` and `lodash`, and also `@types` for them. This command will also place the `@types` packages correctly in `devDependencies`.

We can improve on this even further, because right now it will do a separate `npm` run for every package, and its `@types`. Let's see what else we can do:

```
P='express lodash' eval 'npm i -S $P; npm i -D `echo $P | sed -E "s/[a-z0-9]+/@types\/&/g"`'
```

This will run `npm i` two times, as expected:

1. `npm i -S express lodash`
2. `npm i -D @types/express @types/lodash`

This is the most feature-complete way to do it, but might be too heavy-duty for most cases.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh wow this is interesting, but it seems more painful than the "classic" way. I'm just looking for a simple way, but maybe there is not. Anyway, thanks for your help.